# How do I disable the "Continue to payment" button before the shipping method is selected?

Tags: commerce

How do I disable the *Continue to payment* button before the shipping method is selected?
I use `#states` to disable the button, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I would've assumed form states would do the trick, but without seeing the code you've tried, it's hard to say what the issue might be. That said, we did *just* get the patch into Commerce Shipping that automatically calculates shipping upon full address entry and recalculates it on address change. I believe that may resolve the issue that led you to look into this in the first place. You can upgrade to Commerce Shipping 2.x-dev or apply this patch: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping/issues/2849756#comment-14030351